# PrimeNG listbox selecting all instead of one at time

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I am using angular 4 and prime ng 4.3.0 to display an object; however when i select an item the whole lists select instead of just one row at a time.. is something wrong with how i defined the element?

```
 <p-listbox formControlName="userRole" [options]="this.userRoleItems"   [(ngModel)]="selectedUserRoles" multiple="multiple" [style]='{"width":"650px"}'  checkbox="checkbox" filter="filter"
               >
               <ng-template let-userRole let-i="index" pTemplate="item" optionLabel="userRole.description">
                  {{userRole.code}}  <span style="float:right">{{userRole.description}}</span>

              </ng-template>
              </p-listbox>
```

It is doing this:
[image]

```
export class UserRole {
    public id: number;
    public name: string;
    public code: string
    public description: string;
    public branchId: number;
    public branchName: string;
}
```

Comment: can you include your *.component.ts code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a `value` property in your object.
There are no `optionValue` attribute for the moment in the component.

Sample code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
export class UserRole {
      value: number;
      rolename: string;
  }
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'app/app.template.html'
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  userRoleItems: UserRole[] = [{value: 2, description: 'test'},
  {value: 3, description: 'test'},
  ]; 

  selectedUserRoles:any[] = [];


   ngOnInit() {

   }
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/yRVlQgDKz9tSQgiY65lH?p=preview